# Java - How to include 2 classes in the same file?

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I am trying to Include two or more classes in one file, but java just throws this error message at me!
How would I include 2 or more classed in 1 file?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javaapp.main(javaapp.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class functions1 is public, should be declared in a file named functions1.java
    at functions1.<clinit>(javaapp.java:11)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1



public class functions1 {
    public String Print(String text){
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;
    }
}

public class javaapp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        functions1 Func = new functions1();
        Func.Print("You're learning Java!!!!!");


    }

}
```

Comment: Either make one class a nested class of the other, or put them in two different files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juned Ahsan's answer is right but if you want use 2 classes in the same file, you have one option.Use `inner class`. Check this sample

```
public class OuterClass {
    int outerVariable = 100;

    class InnerClass {
        int innerVariable = 20;

        int someMethod(int parameter) {
           //Do something.
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
        InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass(); 
        System.out.println(inner.someMethod(3));
    }
}
```

And also check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) from oracle.

Comment: thanks man, I really appreciate it! Im learning java right now I was just a little confuzzled!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't feel sorry for downvote.Just ask what you want and share your answer to the others.Then you can be a StackOverflower.

Comment: @MaoKnight it's general practice on Stackoverflow to vote up accepted answers.

Comment: Note, You can have two public classes. class InnerClass can also be public because it's a nested class. It will however still create two .class files

Comment: @MaoKnight See [nested classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one public class in a compilation unit or .java file. Your code should give the desired output if you just take the public specifier out of your `functions1` class

```
public class functions1 {
```

convert to

```
class functions1 {
```

Answer (score -1):

Sir you should use inner class it is a better option where you can access you class fields privately and your class code will be separate

Comment: An inner class has its uses, but I would be far from calling it a "better" option.